# How to retrieve different categories from a news website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to retrieve different categories from a news website. I am using BeautifulSoup to get title of articles from right side. How can I loop to various categories available on the left side of the website? I just started learning this kind of code so much behind understanding how it works. Any help would be appreciated.This is the website I am working on. http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/*/
Below is my code which returns the headlines of various articles from the right side:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from urllib2 import urlopen 
from urllib2 import HTTPError 
from urllib2 import URLError
import requests


resp = urlopen("https://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json")

content = resp.read()
j = json.loads(content)

articles = j['response']['docs']
headlines = [ article['headline']['main'] for article in articles ]
for article in articles:
    print article['headline']['main']
```

Comment: If you are querying the api directly there is no need to use `BeautifulSoup`, use the `requests` module you are already importing.

Comment: Thanks @drec4s I fixed that.

Comment: What are the categories you are trying to get? Business, Sports, etc?

Comment: @drec4s I am trying to get news articles title from different date range example past 24 hours, past 7 days so on.

Comment: You don't have to use the `json` module to handle JSON responses. You can use the `requests` module and its built-in `.json()` function. `j = requests.get(url).json()`

Comment: @KeyurPotdar: I will try that. I am super new to these concepts that it will take me time to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can get those articles by changing the api query like this:

```
import requests

data_range = ['24hours', '7days', '30days', '365days']
news_feed = {}

with requests.Session() as s:

   for rng in data_range:
        news_feed[rng] = s.get('http://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json?begin_date={}ago&facet=true'.format(rng)).json()
```

And access the values like this:

```
print(news_feed) #or print(news_feed['30days'])
```

**EDIT**

To query aditional pages, you may try this:

```
import requests

data_range = ['7days']
news_feed = {}
news_list = []
page = 1

with requests.Session() as s:
   for rng in data_range:
        while page < 20: #this is limited to 120
            news_list.append(s.get('http://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json?begin_date={}ago&page={}&facet=true'.format(rng, page)).json())
            page += 1
        news_feed[rng] = news_list

for new in news_feed['7days']:
    print(new)
```

Comment: for some reason it does not print any newsn before today's date even if I change it to 7 days.

Comment: Well, that's because of the pagination...the query only returns 10 results per page. See the edit to see how to query more pages.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of using `urllib` + `json` to parse the JSON response, you can use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module and its built-in [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) function.

Example:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json")
json_data = r.json()
# rest of the code is same
```

Now, to scrape the `Date Range` tabs, first, go to `Developer Tools` > `Network` > `XHR`. Then, click on any of the tabs. For example, if you click on the `Past 24 Hours` tab, you'll see an AJAX request made to this URL:

```
http://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json?begin_date=24hoursago&facet=true
```

If you click on `Past 7 Days`, you'll see this URL:

```
http://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json?begin_date=7daysago&facet=true
```

In general, you can format these URLs using this:

```
url = "http://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json?begin_date={}&facet=true"
past_24_hours = url.format('24hoursago')

r = requests.get(past_24_hours)
data = r.json()
```

This will get you all the NEWS items in the JSON object `data`.

For example, you can get the NEWS titles like this:

```
for item in data['response']['docs']:
    print(item['headline']['main'])
```

Output:

```
Austrian Lawmakers Vote to Hinder Smoking Ban in Restaurants and Bars
Soccer-Argentine World Cup Winner Houseman Dies Aged 64
Response to UK Spy Attack Not Expected at EU Summit: French Source
Florida Man Reunites With Pet Cat Lost 14 Years Ago
Citigroup Puts Restrictions on Gun Sales
EU Exemptions From U.S. Steel Tariffs 'Possible but Not Certain': French Source
Trump Initiates Trade Action Against China
Trump’s Trade Threats Put China’s Leader on the Spot
Poland Plans Concessions in Judicial Reforms to Ease EU Concerns: Lawmaker
Florida Bridge Collapse Victim's Family Latest to Sue
```